# How to connect a Asp.net website to Oracle Database on a Networked Computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, networking

I am using **Visual Studio 2010** nd ***Config.XML*** has the following code:

```
<connectionstring ModuleId="2" Type="ORA" ConntecionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.129.11.232)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID=ORCL)(SERVER = dedicated)));User ID=utcfms_db26Aug14;Password=utcfms_db26Aug14;"/>
```

On Running the application following errors are encountered:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

*Server has **Oracle 11g** Installed and I have installed* `win64_11gR2_client` *on Client Machine.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Had to install **`32-bit Oracle Client` *`(win32_11gR2_client)`*** on my 64-bit Operating System as the server was hosted in a 64-Bit OS. But the **Oracle** installed was a *32-bit Application.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the oracle client library you are using and the application is a mismatched (32bit or 64bit version). you can either get the correct .dll or change your applications CPU setting to the version of your dll (32bit or 64bit).

Comment: I am having 64-Bit Windows 8.1 and Server is also having windows 8 64-bit but oracle installed on server is a 32-bit Software.

I have installed 64-bit client.

Comment: I am able to connect OracleSQLDevoloper to The Oracle server.